# reading .doc, .docx, .pdf, .rtf documents in .net without Word

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, docx, .doc

so far it's only aspose words but which is very pricey

other are to convert to .pdf or to print to .pdf

I am looking for a way to read the contents of these doc types without installing office or pdf app
i.e. get the text of these documents for parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress offers a document server component now, which is far less pricey than Aspose.

Comment: looks great, only thing missing is .pdf from here http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Rich_Editor/formats.xml   any recommendations for .pdf to text ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use components that plug into the IFilter framework, which is what windows uses to index documents for its text search.

For office documents you can use [Office 2010 Filter Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17062)
For pdf, you can use a commercial offering such as [FoxIt IFilter](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/ifilter/), which seems fairly priced.

Comment: can i use ifilter components in my .net code to get the text ? haven't seen that yet !!